# Curl (bash) command not working in Jenkinsfile groovy script

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In my Jenkinsfile Groovy script, I have the following code;

```
stage('Test the 500 log URLs') {
      steps {
        script {
          echo 'Testing the URLs from the 500 error access log...'
                sh '''#!/bin/bash
                    while IFS= read -r line; do
                      URL=`echo $line | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/http:/https:/' `
                      RESULT=`curl -LI $URL -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n" -s | tr -d '[:space:]' `
                      if [[ $RESULT != "200" ]]
                        then
                          echo "$RESULT $URL"   
                      fi
                    done < tests/Smoke/logs_testing/500errors.txt
                  '''
        }
      }
    }
```

The first parts of the file work correctly, including the command;

```
URL=`echo $line | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/http:/https:/' `
```

However, the following line;

```
RESULT=`curl -LI $URL -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n" -s | tr -d '[:space:]' `
```

fails when I run the Jenkins build.

The following error is produced;

```
line 4: curl: command not found
```

I can't see why the previous line ran ok, but this line is failing.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Does Jenkins actually respect the shebang? (If not, the `[[` will probably raise an error.) The mostly likely problem is not with the script itself, but that `curl` isn't available on the Jenkins host.

Comment: Please read the error again: `curl: command not found`. It's saying that it can't find `curl` to execute. It's not installed.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that `curl` was not installed in a common location like `/usr/bin/`. I'd suggest you try to run curl via its full path.

```
$ which curl
/usr/somelocation/curl # <- just an example
```

Then in your script:

```
RESULT=`/usr/somelocation/curl -LI $URL...`
```

Another option is to edit your `/etc/profile` and append to `PATH` wherever `curl` is located.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/somelocation/
```

Answer (score -1):

Many thanks for you reply. You were right, curl wasn't installed! Running curl via it's full path and then amending my script has now resolved the problem. Thank you! :)