# post-receive hook curl not found

Tags: git, curl, jenkins, githooks

I have problem with automatic build of my project on Jenkins. I've created post-receive hook file:

```
 #!/bin/bash
curl --user myJenkinsLogin:APIToken -s http://myJenkinsUrl/job/JenkinsProjectName/build?token=AuthToken
```

But when I commit and push changes to my repo, after push i got a message:

`remote: hooks/post-receive: line 2: curl: command not found`

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curl (bash) command not working in Jenkinsfile groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53283775/curl-bash-command-not-working-in-jenkinsfile-groovy-script)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjenkins%5D+curl%3A+command+not+found

Comment: #porgo, Do you fix your problem with #phd suggestion?

Comment: @JRichardsz No, I didnt fix this. I ran this curl command from ssh command line and everything is ok. But when im doing push to repo, still getting error.

Comment: @JRichardsz ok, I tried to add full path to curl in my post-receive hook, and now everything is ok :)

Comment: Maybe is a permissions error of your jenkins user. You could check if $PATH value is the same in ssh guest versus ssh jenkins.